# Filter Tableau dashboard by selecting a table column

Tags: filter, visualization, tableau-api

I have multiple visualizations in a dashboard and I'm trying to filter all of these views based on various fields which are all specified in one of the views.

For example:
The first view is a table which has columns like University, City, Population, Tuition fees, Ranking, Growth %.

The second view is a graph which shows top 10 universities based on population.

I want to be able to change the second view to "top 10 universities based on ranking" when a user selects the "Ranking" column in the first view.

Comment: What should the second view display if no columns are selected in first view?

Comment: By default it can be based on population